# Capturing all the occurrences of a specific word when is not part of a link

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to get with a regex using PCRE2 dialect from an HTML text all the occurrences of the word 'apple'. But excluding when the word apple it's part of a link.
I'm quite a beginner with Regex, probably I'm doing quite a simple mistake.

```
\bapple\b
```

So, the following text has to match the first occurrence but not the second and third one.

```
Lorem ipsum apple sit amet, consectetur <a href="#">apple</a> elit <a href="/test/apple">lorem</a>.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You wanna to match whole 4th line? or just 'Match Me'?

Comment: Is the set of tags that would wrap 'Foo Bar' finite? Is it just <span> .... </span> or can it be other tags, like <em>, <strong>, <b>, etc? Is it supposed to take into account invalid or sloppy html, like: <span>foo bar</div>, or things like <h2>foo bar</h2> as well?

Comment: just saw your comment, just the Match Me on the 4th line- see my edited question.

Comment: lizardx- there may be other tags, anything that would be valid inside an <a> tag. Theoretically there won't be any sloppy html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PCRE, you may use this regex:

```
~(?is)<a .*?</a>(*SKIP)(*F)|\bapple\b~
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2yi6sl/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?is)`: Enable ignore case and DOTALL modes
- `<a .*?</a>`: Match text from `<a` to `</a>` to skip all `<a>` tage
- `(*SKIP)(*F)`: together provide a nice alternative of restriction that you cannot have a variable length lookbehind in PCRE regex
- `|`: OR
- `\bapple\b`: Match word `apple`

Answer (score 2):

Matching HTML is quite tricky with regex. The accepted answer here doesn't allow for strings where the match is between two separate anchor tags, for example:

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Don't Match Me <span>web</span></a>
match me
<a href="#">Don't Match Me</a>match me<a href="#">Don't Match Me</a>
```

I have used the following regex before for this but this will only work in php:
https://regex101.com/r/v0FfFC/1

```php
<a[^>]*>(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\s'\-\.,]|(?:<(.*)>.*<\/\1>))*<\/a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b(match me)\b(?=[^>]*(?:<|$))
```

Comment: Thanks for taking another look at this. You were right about fitting in between two anchors. For prosperity, the regex is `/<a[^>]*>(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\s'\-\.,]|(?:<(.*)>.*<\/\1>))*<\/a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b(match me)\b(?=[^>]*(?:<|$))/gi`

Comment: Thanks, it might need tweaking for individual use cases

Answer (score 1):

Comment upgrade to answer:

```
match me(?!.*?\<\/a\>)
```

https://regex101.com/r/hH3rL1/1

Comment: This is the accepted answer but it doesn't seem to work on my regex engine (Sublime Text 2)... it matches all lines.

Comment: However this doesn't work where a wanted match is between 2 anchor tags i.e. `<a href="#">Don't Match Me</a> match me <a href="#">Don't Match Me</a>`

Answer (score 0):

I changed your regex to look for anchors and avoid select that line.

```
/^(?!.*(\<a.*?\>)).*$/ism
```

https://regex101.com/r/kE4mJ0/1

Comment: mayo- thanks so much for taking a look at this. I guess I wasn't crystal clear. These aren't necessarily on separate lines, it could just the same be <a href="#">Don't Match Me <span>web</span></a><a href="#">Don't Match Me</a>Match Me <span>Match Me</span>. And I need to be able to match the specific text "Match Me"... unless it's inside an anchor tag.

Comment: match me(?!.*?\<\/a\>) does that work for yopur problem?

Comment: yeah, I think that's it! Mind adding it as an answer?

Comment: Seems like @user993553's solution is what are you looking for !

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP regex is PCRE2-based, you can use a [`(*SKIP)(*F)`/`(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex):

```php
/<a(?:\s[^>]*)?>.*?<\/a>(*SKIP)(*F)|\bMatch Me\b/is
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BnaaZe/2).

**Details**

- `<a` - `<a` or `<A` (as the `i` flag is used, the pattern is case insensitive)
- `(?:\s[^>]*)?` - an optional occurrence of a whitespace char (`\s`) and then any zero or more chars other than `>` (see `[^>]*`) (this part makes sure we match `<a>` as well as `<a attr=value attr2=value2...>` kinds of tags)
- `>` - a `>` char
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars, as few as possible (`s` flag makes `.` match line break chars, too)
- `<\/a>` - `</a>` or `</A>`
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - skip the match and go on to look for further matches from the position where the failure occurred
- `|` - or
- `\bMatch Me\b` - a whole word `Match me` (not enclosed with letters, digits or `_` chars).